# Find the volume of B given an equation for A

Tags: analytic-geometry

We define a solid A by: $$\frac{19}{x^2} + \frac{14}{y^2} \leq z^4 \quad (0 \leq z \leq 1)$$

We define a solid B by: $$x^2 + y^2 \leq z^4 \quad (0 \leq z \leq 1)$$

> **The volume of the solid B is ?**

Please **don't tell me the answer**, just guide/tell me the things i need to know to solve the problem, i search on youtube *"find volume from solid equation"*, but only got videos calculating known geometric figures.

Comment: Are you looking for the volume of $B$ in terms of the volume of $A,$ or on its own? If it's the former, then you'll likely want to look at how you can transform $B$ into $A$ or vice versa. If it's the latter, we'll likely need to do some integration. (which also doesn't seem so terrible if we use polar)

Comment: I suppose that i'm looking for the volume of $B$ by its own, since the exercise above is an exact copy from the paper, with nothing else

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be honest, in that case I don't quite understand why we've defined $A.$ Anyway, are you familiar with multiple integration and cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but knowing that is a step further

Comment: you can find an entire version of this problem [here](https://imgur.com/a/RBuRgxY)